# How to add a class to a hyperlink when it contains a specific file extension?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, regex

Can someone tell me how to take a string and run a function against it to check for a specific type of file (say a ".pdf"). If the string contains the file, then it needs to apply a "pdf" class to the anchor that contains the link.

Here's an example of a string:

```
<a href="/downloads/myfile.pdf">My PDF</a>
```

I would like it to be changed to this:

```
<a href="/downloads/myfile.pdf" class="pdf">My PDF</a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this in CSS:

```
a[href$=".pdf"] {
   /* some rules */
}
```

But this may not be supported by some browser.

Alternatively, do this in Javascript, with jQuery or any library:

```
$('a[href$=".pdf"]').addClass('pdf'); // in jQuery
```

Or without library:

```
var elems = document.getElementByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i  < elems.length; ++i) {
    var a = elems[i];
    if (/\.pdf$/.test(a.href)) {
        a.className = 'pdf';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Those are good solutions, however it needs to be supported in IE6/7 (so no CSS) and I was hoping to be able to do this without any JS, thus using server-side code to apply it -- I'm just not great with PHP. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`(<a\s+href="[^"]*\.([A-Za-z0-9]{2,5})\s*")([^>]*>)`
replace by 
`\1 class="\2" \3`

python code:

```
import re,sys
file = sys.argv[1]
f = open(file, 'r')
text = f.read()
f.close()
text = re.sub(r'(<a\s+href="[^"]*\.([A-Za-z0-9]{2,5})\s*")([^>]*>)', r'\1 class="\2" \3', te$
f = open(file+'.re','w')
f.write(text)
f.close()
```

Can use it to modify html static